# Evaluate: $\int \sec (x-a) \sec (x-b)\; dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to do this integration: $$\int \sec (x-a) \sec (x-b)\ dx?$$

I want to this in the shortest possible way. Please guide me through.

Comment: Hint:  try using $\sec(y) = 1/\cos(y)$ and $\cos(y)\cos(z) = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(y+z)+\cos(y-z)]$

Comment: By "solve" I guess you mean "evaluate"...

Comment: Have you made any progress by using Dilip's hint?

Comment: Probably not the _shortest possible way_ but you can try to: 1. Type "integrate 1/[cos(x-a)*cos(x-b)]" into wolframalpha; 2. wait for a while; 3. click on "show steps" 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%5Bcos%28x-a%29%2Acos%28x-b%29%5D

Answer (score 11):

This can be done via the following trick. Rewrite your integral
as $${1 \over \sin(b - a)} \int {\sin(b - a) \over \cos(x - a)\cos(x - b)}\,dx$$
Note that $b - a = (x - a) - (x -b)$, so by the sine subtraction formula you have
$$\sin(b - a) = \sin(x - a)\cos(x - b) - \sin(x - b)\cos(x - a)$$
Subtituting this back into your integral it becomes
$${1 \over \sin(b - a)} \bigg(\int \tan(x - a)\,dx- \int \tan( x - b)\,dx\bigg)$$
$$ = {1 \over \sin(b - a)} \bigg(-\ln(\cos(x - a)) + \ln(\cos(x - b))\bigg) + C$$

Comment: I was typing the same answer!

Comment: gotta be fast here ;)

Comment: Yeah,this is actually a text book problem :)